# looking for more pythonic apporach

Tags: python

Just wrote this function...

```
def nrofleadingchars(stringtotest, testchar='\t'):
    count = 0
    for c in stringtotest:
        if c == testchar:
            count = count + 1
        else:
            return count
    return count
```

However does not feel pythonic 'enough', suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the code is straightforward, so you should prefer it to some unreadable mess.
I would just shorten it a bit:

```
def nrofleadingchars(stringtotest, testchar='\t'):
    count = 0
    for c in stringtotest:
        if c != testchar:
            break
        count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: also: `count += 1` is a bit better.

Comment: yep, should have used a break (shame on me)

Comment: You could also skip the `count` variable entirely by using `enumerate()` in your `for` loop and just returning the index if not equal, and the `len()` of the input if you finish the loop.

Comment: I agree with acondolu. "Explicit is better than implicit." To be that "pythonic" is maybe "cool", but its the less readable, usable way to go. Especially in this case its a little too "pythonic". oO

Comment: the shoe should always fit... that is: for me - for now - this solution is very clear

Answer (score 9):

```
import itertools

def nrofleadingchars(stringtotest, testchar='\t'):
    return len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x == testchar, stringtotest)))
```

Due to the need to construct a list, this could be less efficient for things with very large prefixes. If I were going to potentially be dealing with such, I'd probably write this instead:

```
def num_leading_chars(a_string, prefix='\t'):
    for idx, char in enumerate(a_string):
        if char != prefix:
            return idx
    return len(a_string)
```

Comment: I see, lot of miles to cover for me, thanx!

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what about the performance of this code when compared to that of OP? I know just enough of Python to be able to read it and this seems to be quite performance-hitter to me. What's more, I actually consider OP's code to be more readable (but that's just a matter of preference, I guess).

Comment: @NikolaAnusev `itertools` is implemented in C. For larger inputs, it's generally pretty darn efficient. For small inputs, the overhead of a function call may make it slower... but for small inputs, you generally don't care about the speed. However, for inputs with a large prefix size, this probably *would* be less efficient, due to constructing a list. I've edited in another version that would avoid that inefficiency.

Comment: @Amber Thanks for the answer and the revised version of your code - yet again I learned something new.

Answer (score 5):

You could strip leading characters that match and calculate the difference based on the length.

```
def nrofleadingchars(stringtotest, testchar='\t'):
    return (len(stringtotest) - len(stringtotest.lstrip(testchar))
```

Comment: this is much better ofcourse, I didn't know the optional lstrip parameter, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-answer, but I don't know how to put this information here.

In case performance is also a consideration (it always is for me), here is a report of the current answers.

```
                          nrofleadingchars_orig |        nrofleadingchars_1 |       nrofleadingchars_it |         num_leading_chars |      nrofleadingchars_len
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nrofleadingchars_ori:                       1.0 |             1.05393899527 |            0.603740407137 |              1.2923361749 |             23.1678811895
  nrofleadingchars_1:            0.948821520491 |                       1.0 |            0.572841891082 |             1.22619637446 |             21.9821842568
 nrofleadingchars_it:             1.65634101706 |             1.74568238735 |                       1.0 |             2.14054941432 |             38.3739118926
   num_leading_chars:            0.773792469344 |            0.815530057691 |            0.467169780482 |                       1.0 |             17.9271319951
nrofleadingchars_len:           0.0431632047756 |            0.045491384674 |           0.0260593708246 |           0.0557813709562 |                       1.0
```

These are timing ratios. Down first column can  be read as "times slower".